# Unable to inspect element when in Selenium java code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, safari

Help me to inspect element - I search for "Yanni Nightingale songs" and want to click the Youtube video.

I tried various option like below to use in Selenium java code but nothing working.

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Yanni - ”Nightingale”… The “Tribute” Concerts!... 1080p Digitally Remastered & Restored")).click();


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dFk3Oe gcwZKd tNxQIb ynAwRc OSrXXb'][")).click();
```

But unable to click the link. Any suggestion

```
<a class="X5OiLe" aria-label="Yanni - ”Nightingale”… The “Tribute” Concerts!... 1080p ...&nbsp;by Yanni. Play on YouTube. 7 minutes, 25 seconds. 10 Mar 2019" href="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjD86C6tcyBAxVKb_UHHWVqC18QwqsBegQICRAG&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DmfCca7M5r9A&amp;usg=AOvVaw3R-HacML6UztJ3LqUORPUD&amp;opi=89978449" data-jsarwt="1" data-usg="AOvVaw3R-HacML6UztJ3LqUORPUD" data-ved="2ahUKEwjD86C6tcyBAxVKb_UHHWVqC18QwqsBegQICRAG" data-ctbtn="2" data-cthref="/url?sa=t&amp;rct=j&amp;q=&amp;esrc=s&amp;source=web&amp;cd=&amp;cad=rja&amp;uact=8&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjD86C6tcyBAxVKb_UHHWVqC18QwqsBegQICRAG&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DmfCca7M5r9A&amp;usg=AOvVaw3R-HacML6UztJ3LqUORPUD&amp;opi=89978449" data-jrwt="1"><div class="WZIVy" aria-level="3" role="heading"><div class="uOId3b"><div class="fc9yUc tNxQIb ynAwRc OSrXXb"><span class="cHaqb">Yanni - ”Nightingale”… The “Tribute” Concerts!... 1080p ...</span></div></div><div class="FzCfme"><span class="pcJO7e"><cite>YouTube</cite><span><span aria-hidden="true"> ·</span> Yanni</span></span><div><div class="V8fWH">7 minutes, 25 seconds</div></div><div class="hMJ0yc"><span>10 Mar 2019</span></div></div></div></a>
```

Comment: Hi Suvechcha try the following xpath and it should work //a[contains(@aria-label,"Yanni - \”Nightingale\”")]